# Generating tree sort of structure using RxAndroid

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying my hand out and RxAndroid. I have my sync adapter querying Service A to get a List Pages(size n). For each item in Pages I have to make a request which generates another Lines(size m). That is for each item in Pages there will be m Lines.I want to combine all the n Lines into 1 list of size m*n and persist into the db .

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Page>(){
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Page> subscriber) {

            ArrayList<Page> pages = Utility.getPagesFromServer();
            for (Page page : pages) {
                subscriber.onNext(page);
            }
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }


    }).map(new Func1<Page, JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public JSONResponse call(Page page) {

            return Utility.getJSONObjectContainingLines(page);

        }
    }).map(new Func1<JSONResponse, ArrayList<Line>>() {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<Line> call(JSONResponse jsonResponse) {
            return getLines(jsonResponse.getJSONObject());
        }
    })
```

I get pages from the server, then map and fetch the lines for each page from the server and then I parse the JSON and get the arrayList of lines. I am unsure how to proceed from here . As to now I want to iterate on each Line and not on each ArrayList .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After last `map( )` use `.flatMapIterable( )` and you will transform `Observable<ArrayList<Line>>` to `Observable<Line>` and in `onNext(Line l)` iterate its(or use `forEach( )`):

```
    Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Page>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Page> call() {
            return Observable.from(Utility.getPagesFromServer());
        }
    })
    .map(new Func1<Page, JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public JSONResponse call(Page page) {
            return Utility.getJSONObjectContainingLines(page);
        }
    })
    .map(new Func1<JSONResponse, ArrayList<Line>>() {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<Line> call(JSONResponse jsonResponse) {
            return getLines(jsonResponse.getJSONObject());
        }
    })
    .flatMapIterable(new Func1<ArrayList<Line>, Iterable<Line>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Line> call(ArrayList<Line> lines) {
            return lines;
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Line>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Line line) {
            //Do something with your line
        }
    }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            //on complete
        }
    });
```

Or using `Lambdas`:

```
    Observable.defer(() -> Observable.from(Utility.getPagesFromServer()))
    .map(page -> Utility.getJSONObjectContainingLines(page))
    .map(jsonResponse -> getLines(jsonResponse.getJSONObject()))
    .flatMapIterable(lines -> lines)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(line -> {
        //Do something with your line
    }, throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace(), () -> {
        //on complete
    });
```

**UPDATE:**
I decided to add some some links:
[Transforming-Observables](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables)
[flatmap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)

As you can see to transform `Observable<ArrayList<Line>>` to `Observable<Line>` you should use operator `flatMapIterable()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also can you tell me why did you use defer instead of Observable.defer instead of Observable.create ?

Comment: @Abhik, you're welcome. `Utility.getPagesFromServer()` may take a lot of time, because most probably it uses network operations(I conclude it from the title). Using `defer( )` you can guarantee, that this operation will not be executed on main thread. Else, it will be executed on main thread, and most probably you should get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Use `defer( )` to avoid it

Comment: @Abhik, you can read about it here: http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/

Comment: I get it. But I am doing it in my Sync adapters which is not my main thread . Can you tell me , in this case do I really need defer ?

Comment: @Abhik in this case, of course is optional(And may be redundantly). I just missed, that you are creating `Observable` in `SyncAdapter`